# Nested forEach loops unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, poker

In my poker app I have an array of hands, each hand being array of randomly selected card objects with value and suit:

```
[ [ { value: 5, suit: 's' },
    { value: 4, suit: 's' },
    { value: 6, suit: 'c' },
    { value: 11, suit: 'd' },
    { value: 12, suit: 'c' } ],
  [ { value: 9, suit: 'd' },
    { value: 12, suit: 'h' },
    { value: 8, suit: 'c' },
    { value: 12, suit: 's' },
    { value: 2, suit: 's' } ],
  [ { value: 4, suit: 'h' },
    { value: 6, suit: 's' },
    { value: 10, suit: 'c' },
    { value: 3, suit: 'd' },
    { value: 7, suit: 'd' } ] ]
```

To prepare the hands for evaluation I want to return an array of hand objects, each with an array of `values` and `suits`. So the output would be:

```
[ 
  { 
    values: [5, 4, 6, 11, 12],
    suits: ['s', 's', 'c', 'd', 'c'] 
  },      
  { 
    values: [9, 12, 8, 12, 2], 
    suits: ['d', 'h', 'c', 's', 's'] 
  },
  { 
    values: [4, 6, 10, 3, 7],
    suits: ['h', 's', 'c', 'd', 'd'] 
  } 
]
```

I'm trying to use nested forEach loops to achieve this, like so:

```
let temp = []
hands.forEach((el) => {
  temp = el
  el = {}
  el.values = []
  el.suits = []
  temp.forEach((obj) => {
    el.values.push(obj.value)
    el.suits.push(obj.suit)
    console.log(el) //expected output
  })
  console.log(el) //expected output
})
console.log(hands) //same as original
```

However as the comments outline, it behaves as expected until the loop has finished, where `hands` has not changed at all. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forEach` does not change the array on which it was called, it simply iterates the array calling a function for each element. If you want to build a new array inside that function, just do so

```
var newArray = [];
hands.forEach((el) => {
   var newValue = // do something here
   newArray.push(newValue);
});
```

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```js
var hands = [ [ { value: 5, suit: 's' },
    { value: 4, suit: 's' },
    { value: 6, suit: 'c' },
    { value: 11, suit: 'd' },
    { value: 12, suit: 'c' } ],
  [ { value: 9, suit: 'd' },
    { value: 12, suit: 'h' },
    { value: 8, suit: 'c' },
    { value: 12, suit: 's' },
    { value: 2, suit: 's' } ],
  [ { value: 4, suit: 'h' },
    { value: 6, suit: 's' },
    { value: 10, suit: 'c' },
    { value: 3, suit: 'd' },
    { value: 7, suit: 'd' } ] ];

let newValues = []
hands.forEach((el) => {
  var temp = {values:[], suits:[]};
  el.forEach((obj) => {
    temp.values.push(obj.value)
    temp.suits.push(obj.suit)
    
  })
  newValues.push(temp);
})
console.log(newValues) // NOT same as original
```

There is many ways to achieve this same thing, the best I could come up with is below - and avoids the double `hand.map` seen in other answers (which is pretty inefficient).

```js
var hands = [ [ { value: 5, suit: 's' },
    { value: 4, suit: 's' },
    { value: 6, suit: 'c' },
    { value: 11, suit: 'd' },
    { value: 12, suit: 'c' } ],
  [ { value: 9, suit: 'd' },
    { value: 12, suit: 'h' },
    { value: 8, suit: 'c' },
    { value: 12, suit: 's' },
    { value: 2, suit: 's' } ],
  [ { value: 4, suit: 'h' },
    { value: 6, suit: 's' },
    { value: 10, suit: 'c' },
    { value: 3, suit: 'd' },
    { value: 7, suit: 'd' } ] ];

let newValues = hands.map(h => {
      return h.reduce( (p,c) => {
            p.values.push(c.value);
            p.suits.push(c.suit);
            return p;
        },{values:[], suits:[]});
  });

console.log(newValues) // NOT same as original
```

Comment: Although that said, why keep using `forEach`? this is what we added `map` to the Array API for.

Comment: I agree, I would not write this in the way the OP did, but for the sake of keeping the code as close to the original as possible...

Comment: if the original code is bad code, we're here to help people write better code, too. The sooner OP learns to use map for these things, the better their code contributions to the world at large will be, including future answers by them on SO.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `map` being "better" is entirely subjective. Using `map` is not magically "better" than `forEach`.

Comment: Readability disagrees with that statement. Code is not written and never looked at again, it's typically written and then maintained by someone else entirely, so write code that can be read at a glance, without sacrificing performance (for instance by using `reduce`, as you suggest, either up front or when profiling shows the code as being bottleneck performance bottleneck)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> hands.forEach((el) => {
> ```

You assign each object in the array, in turn, to the variable `el`.

> ```
> el = {}
> ```

You overwrite **the variable** `el` with a reference to a new object.

`el` is no longer connected to its original value.

You are **just** replacing the value of `el`. The **properties in the array** are still pointing to the **original** objects.

---

To change the objects in the original array, you need to assign a new object to them explicitly.

```
hands.forEach((originalValue, index, array) => {
  // originalValue is what you used to call `temp`
  // Just make `el` a new object
  var el = {};
  // Put it in the array
  array[index] = el;
  // Then continue as before
```

Answer (score 1):

Let JavaScript do this for you instead of writing lots of code, by taking advantage of the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function that arrays support:

```
let rewritten = data.map(hand => {
  return {
    values: hand.map(card => card.value),
    suits: hand.map(card => card.suit),
  } 
});
```

(with the outer `{ return` and `}` in the arrow function being unnecessary if you put it all on the same line, but for the purposes of an answer that makes it far less readable of course)

This takes your original data, which is already and array sized on hands (three in this case), and then applies a transform to each hand. Specifically, it creates a new object where the array of "values and suits" have been turned into an array of "just values", using `map`, and an array of "just suits", also using `map`.

Arrays in JavaScript come with a number of utility functions for packing/unpacking/iterating/transforming, and it's worth giving those a read through. They allow you to do big things with very little code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array is worth a read if you've not read up on the API for arrays in a while, or ever. It also explains how to use `recude` for instance, which can be used to make this code more efficient (see Jamiec's answer above for that).

Comment: Persoanlly, think this is a *terrible* way to solve the problem - you're unnecessarily iterating over `hand` twice in each loop, which is not great - learn to use `reduce`

Comment: even better, looking forward to seeing your answer with reduce instead.

Comment: awesome, upvoted. I'd name the vars after what they are since a script minifier is going to make them single letters anyway, but that's again me thinking as someone who is going to inherit this code, it doesn't make the code itself run better of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the values directly in an object for the properties.

```js
var data = [[{ value: 5, suit: 's' }, { value: 4, suit: 's' }, { value: 6, suit: 'c' }, { value: 11, suit: 'd' }, { value: 12, suit: 'c' }], [{ value: 9, suit: 'd' }, { value: 12, suit: 'h' }, { value: 8, suit: 'c' }, { value: 12, suit: 's' }, { value: 2, suit: 's' }], [{ value: 4, suit: 'h' }, { value: 6, suit: 's' }, { value: 10, suit: 'c' }, { value: 3, suit: 'd' }, { value: 7, suit: 'd' }]],

result = data.map(a => (
  { 
    values: a.map(b => b.value), 
    suits: a.map(b => b.suit) 
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could use a less iteration style.

```js
var data = [[{ value: 5, suit: 's' }, { value: 4, suit: 's' }, { value: 6, suit: 'c' }, { value: 11, suit: 'd' }, { value: 12, suit: 'c' }], [{ value: 9, suit: 'd' }, { value: 12, suit: 'h' }, { value: 8, suit: 'c' }, { value: 12, suit: 's' }, { value: 2, suit: 's' }], [{ value: 4, suit: 'h' }, { value: 6, suit: 's' }, { value: 10, suit: 'c' }, { value: 3, suit: 'd' }, { value: 7, suit: 'd' }]],
    keys = ['value', 'suit'],
    result = data.map(
        a => a.reduce(
            (r, b) => (keys.forEach(k => r[k + 's'].push(b[k])), r), { values: [], suits: [] }
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create an object with two properties (values and suits) before the second loop and inject him in the result after this second loop like this :

```js
var hands = [[{ value: 5, suit: 's' }, { value: 4, suit: 's' }, { value: 6, suit: 'c' }, { value: 11, suit: 'd' }, { value: 12, suit: 'c' }], [{ value: 9, suit: 'd' }, { value: 12, suit: 'h' }, { value: 8, suit: 'c' }, { value: 12, suit: 's' }, { value: 2, suit: 's' }], [{ value: 4, suit: 'h' }, { value: 6, suit: 's' }, { value: 10, suit: 'c' }, { value: 3, suit: 'd' }, { value: 7, suit: 'd' }]];
var output = [];
hands.forEach(x => {
  var temp = {values: [], suits: []};
  x.forEach(y => {
    temp.values.push(y.value);
    temp.suits.push(y.suit);
  })
  output.push(temp);
});
console.log(output);
```